# Height of tcolorbox changed by g y p q

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox

I'm using `tcolorbox` to create a box with a text. Unfortunately, if I use characters like `y` `g` `p` `q` and so on, the height of the box is slightly bigger than without:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Hello
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Bye
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve the same box height independently on these characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `\phantom` of the character that makes the difference.  I've chosen to put the same phantom (a tall and a deep character) in each box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Hello\phantom{Hy}
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Bye\phantom{Hy}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of above code]

Strictly speaking you can use `\vphantom` for a vertical correction, and probably should in this case.  Even better is `\strut`, especially if you want to define your own new box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{oneliner}{fontupper=\strut}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{oneliner}
            Hello
        \end{oneliner}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{oneliner}
            Bye
        \end{oneliner}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Pages 15 and 29 of [the tcolorbox manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) explain how to make your own box, and the meaning of the various options.  `\vphantom{y}` in place of `\strut` in the new box definitions doesn't work -- the phantom is set on one line and the real text underneath.

Comment: @Teepeemm good point, added to the answer

Comment: Thank you, working fine. Is there a possibility to add this as a tcolorbox option? I.e. I define a `\newtcolorbox` and want to have the phantom applied to all boxes of this type?

Comment: That would be complicated to do properly, as tcolorbox can handle multiple lines, and that doesn't make sense for phantoms.  Howver you should be able to add `\usepackage{etoolbox} \AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\vphantom{Hy}}` to your preamble if you intend to only use single line tcolorboxes.  I haven't tested it though. Section 2.6 of the [etoolbox manual](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) is relevant

Comment: My plan is to define a `\newtcolorbox{mybox}` and to add`\AtBeginEnvironment{mybox}{\vphantom{Hy}}`. Could be working, unfortunately I won't really have time this week to test it. Thank you again

Comment: @ju. if you're defining your own box it's easier -- se the update to my answer

Comment: works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is `equal height group`. All boxes from same group will have similar height (after two compilations), it doesn't matter if the are on same line or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=A]
            Hello
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=A]
            Bye
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{multicols}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=A]
            aeo
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            aeo
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

yet another workaround could be to use `\strut`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \strut Hello
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \strut Bye
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually this works better than `\vphantom` if you want to define your own box (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 4):

You could set the `text height` explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{text height=2ex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Hello
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Bye
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe to late and useless to answer, but as well for a multiline text (paragraph), one can also use the `tcolorbox` options `after upper`/`after lower` with a (vertical, i. e. zero width) phantom text. To the added phantom text, one subtracts the text depth (strutbox) in order to have the same gap with the box bottom line.

This leads to have an actual control of the vertical skip at the box bottom.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{%
  a4paper, twoside,
  top=27mm, bottom=27mm, inner=20mm, outer=20mm,
  ignorehead, ignorefoot, includemp,
  marginparwidth=52mm, marginparsep=8mm,
  headsep=7mm, headheight=12.2pt, footskip=14mm, showframe
}

\newcommand{\tcbphantom}{\vspace*{-\dp\strutbox}\vphantom{Hg}}

\tcbset{tcbphantom/.style={
    boxsep=0pt, boxrule=2pt,
    top=4pt, bottom=8pt,
    left=4pt, right=4pt,
    after upper=\tcbphantom
  }
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[tcbphantom]
    \lipsum[1] % <-- Last line with "letters having depth"
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[tcbphantom]
    \lipsum[2] % <-- Last line without "letters having depth"
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]