# How to write Bootstrap-like badges in LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, boxes, draw

I need in-line pills like the ones Bootstrap has: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/

How do I go about achieving this in LaTeX/XeTeX?

Comment: Have a look at tcolorbox package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility with the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbox{\badge}[1][red]{
  on line, 
  arc=2pt,
  colback=#1!50!black,
  colframe=#1!50!black,
  fontupper=\color{white},
  boxrule=1pt, 
  boxsep=0pt,
  left=6pt,
  right=6pt,
  top=2pt,
  bottom=2pt
}

\begin{document}

test \badge{test} test \badge[blue]{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To make all the badges the same vertical offset (even if the text includes a `y` or `g` characeter), set `fontupper=\strut\color{white}`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418770/100323

Comment: Is it possible to fix the issue we have in this picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqfaps9xr4cwi0t/Captura%20de%20tela%20de%202023-05-30%2021-48-59.png?dl=0
As you can see in CSS and Heroku the size of the badge is diferent from the rest of the other badges. I think that this has to do with the size of the letters, because in the remaining cases we do not have anything bellow the baseline

I have added a last badge test for you to see that the size is not matching

Comment: @lucasbbs If you have a new question, please ask a new question. More people will see it.